# Check if thread is finished in c++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I need a way to know if the thread I am running is finished or not. If it is not finished it wait and if it is finished print a successful message.

I don't find a method or something like that in c++11 from library thread.
I can't set a global variable because inside thread I am using `execvp` and it does not return if successful.

Is there any way to do that? A method or flag or anything else.

`Edit:` To make it clear I want to write a function that checks if thread is finished.

Comment: Maybe `join` does what you want? Also, won't execvp replace your *entire* process?

Comment: That does not help, I need something like `while (thread not finished){1;} cout <<"thread finished"<<endl;`

Comment: That's what `join` does (except it won't waste processor time to do nothing)...

Comment: I have more than one thread. I don't want to wait until first finish.

Comment: You are giving contradictory requirements ("something like `while (thread not finished){1;}`" and "don't want to wait" are opposites). That makes your stated problem unsolvable. You may want to make the actual requirements more clear if you really want a workable solution.

Comment: If you simply want to wait for one thread to execute, then don't use a thread

Comment: Keep in mind that such a function can only give you meaningful positives; it will generate false negatives, because a `false` result is outdated the moment it is returned.

Comment: That is OK. There is no problem about it.

Comment: Can't you just set a flag `isFinished` and signal a `condition_variable` at the end of the thread?

Comment: As I am using `execvp` it is not possible. Any way I solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [C++11 futures and promises](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html):

> Futures are a high level mechanism for passing a value between threads, and allow a thread to wait for a result to be available without having to manage the locks directly.

The benefits of futures over using plain threads are:

- Future returns a value.
- You can wait on a future with a timeout.

Surely, this can be done with plain threads, but why reimplement a wheel with C++11.

Comment: Call [std::future::wait_until()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until) with a 0 timeout.